# UWP StreamSocket not receiving TLS Alert (21) data

Tags: c#, networking, uwp, wireshark, tls1.2

I'm trying to write an UWP app that communicates with a server using MQTT over HTTPS. I use StreamSocket to send the whole MQTT packet over the wire but I couldn't get any response from server. If I attempt to resend the packet, the server would terminate the connection. Using Wireshark, I can see that the server responded with a message Content-Type: Alert (21) with 26 bytes of data in it but I couldn't read it through StreamSocket.InputStream

```
var streamSocket = new StreamSocket();
Buffer packet;

// Building Mqtt packet.

await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("server.com"), "443", SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12);
await streamSocket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(packet);

await Task.Delay(2000);  // Give the server some time to respond
var inputBytes = new byte[2048];
var completion = await streamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync(inputBytes.AsBuffer(),(uint) inputBytes.Length, InputStreamOptions.Partial);

// inputBytes still empty
```

I want to be able to read the bytes server responded. I think there is a way to access these bytes but I could not find it anywhere.

**Update:** Added Wireshark result

[Wireshark result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htdgX.png)

Comment: Please check [Creating secure socket connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/networking-basics#creating-secure-socket-connections). *You cannot use SSL/TLS with the StreamSocket created by a StreamSocketListener when incoming communications are received, because SSL/TLS negotiation as a server is not implemented by the StreamSocket class*

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT My bad, I didn't copy my code so I made a little mistake here. To clarify I didn't use StreamSocketListener. I just read the socket after the time delay. I even put the read command in an infinite loop with 2 secs delay but still got nothing. Please check out the screenshot I just attached for Wireshark's result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is related with the HTTPS. Have you tried to use the [UpgradeToSslAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.upgradetosslasync) method, if your SSL/TLS connection is desired after sending and receiving some initial data,  please use the [UpgradeToSslAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket.upgradetosslasync) method to upgrade the connection to use SSL as following:

```
await streamSocket.ConnectAsync(new HostName("server.com"), "443", Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketProtectionLevel.PlainSocket);
await streamSocket.UpgradeToSslAsync(Windows.Networking.Sockets.SocketProtectionLevel.Tls12, hostName);
```

Thanks,

Amy Peng